# how to set multible hosts using one server and show them on hotspot or any connected device with [ no web ]

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2.4, hotspot, htdocs

if having this file tree:

```
* www    // localhost    # developer
|\
| * x    // dom1.ext
| |
| * y    // dom2.ext
| |
| * z    // leader.com   # immediately provided site when wifi conect 》 includes links to other domains [ dom1.ext, dom2.ext, ... ]
| /
/
```

I want my local server to provide these domains using hotspot

》 every domain should have a folder in www to provide data from, but all has the same configration files

》 only just who has access to the computer can see the server developer side [ localhost ip is ::1 #satisfy or not ? ]

》 any other should be redirected immediately to [ leader.com ] when conecting to wifi

> this should work if internet is connected or not

---

I tried so much to use "hosts" file to specify a hostname then made apache listen to it using "htdocs.config"

》 host is supplied locally only on device not all network

---

in the config it just use one dir

》 how to use multiple [ one for each domain ]

---

it dosn't matter what ever you used from [ question tags ],
just "how to acheve this or a part of it";
even a small information could help me

Comment: What is "hotspot" in your context? How is this related to PHP or `.htaccess`?

Comment: I need to provide localhost via hotspot put not www dir only specific subdirectories... I kow that htdocs.config could listen to an ip or a pre defined host for ip in hosts file.. .htaccess can change config but only for dir inwhich it's placed... I'm asking if there are any way of previous to make the server listen to a [ host  // not only an ip ] that should be accessable from anywhere in local network [ hotspot/wifi / direct connected device ], each folder with its own domain

Comment: .htaccess may be able to chang dir sitting for listening

Comment: I'm not wanting to just examin my sites only on my device but to be accessable for whoever connect to wifi/hotspot.. I hope there is no confuse

Comment: localhost = current network 127.0.0.1 - as long as usr has connection to wifi/hotspot/whatever network and do 127.0.0.1 usr goes to localhost, you want to set up **vhosts** on your hotspot with dedicated IP so it points a certain ip to a certain site ..

Comment: didn't work,, and it's not the problem,,

Comment: ::1 & 127.0.0.1 is reserved for curent local network so it just runs your vertual server on the device you setted on not any device connected,, I realy specified another ip, made apache listen to it,, but I dont want it to listen only for ip

Comment: in "hosts" I put this [ x.x.x.x overwrote.com ],, this would overwrite overwrote.com in my device to return site with ip x.x.x.x ,, then in "htdocs.config" I made this line [ Listen  overwrote.com ] ,, when running overwrote.com  or x.x.x.x on my pc with the server it works but when using some other device via wifi it only runs x.x.x.x and you need to enter it manualy but I need it to run on overwrote.com ,  when wifi connect automaticly open & also same when reaching 404 respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add entery for your virtual domain in `hosts` file or your virtual/local dns server
2. add `<virtualhost>` tag in `htdocs.config` - one for each virtualhost
3. use the code in your site to iterate over `<virtualhost>` tags and hosts then generate the site list you want